# Get how many characters a line in Textview can have

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

Let's say we have a large String and many textviews which all have `maxLines="1"` and `layout_width="match_parent"`and a monospaced font.

I need to know how many characters of my string I can put in a `Textview` before it needs a new line.

It would be great if the solution could work with `EditText` too.

Comment: You usually don't use a monospaced font, so there is no real solution to this

Comment: Well in this case I do. Correcting the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextPaint paint = textView.getPaint();
int wordwidth=(int)paint.measureText("a",0,1);
int screenwidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int num = screenwidth/wordwidth
```