# Detecting max number of char in TextView when app runnig

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview, android-constraintlayout

Like in topic :)
Is it possible to detect max number of char in TextView when app is running ?
I have textView into ConstraintLayout, which have set layout_width as match_constraint(0dp).

Comment: Do you need to know what max `char` it have or how many `char` it can fill ?

Comment: yes, I want know this @MohammedAlaa

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815703/get-how-many-characters-a-line-in-textview-can-have)

Answer (score 0):

A TextView does not really have a limit of characters when you did not set one.

Comment: but maybe something like, max chars in 1 line :)

Comment: that is dependent of the width of the view and the screen size